# List length comparison

Tags: scheme

I wanted to write the code for comparing the size of two lists. I made use of the length and wrote this down.

```
(define (same-size-matrix? mtrx1 mtrx2)
   (equal? (length mtrx1) (length mtrx2))).
```

I thought this was going to work for me, but I found out it only checks the overall length, not the sublist. For example it returns true when it compares for. '((1 2 3 4) (4 5 6 6) (6 7 8 9)) and '(( 5 4) (3 2) (7 1)), but it's supposed to return false, because the first has 4 values within the list and the second has only two even though they both overally have same length. How do I go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
(define (same-size-matrix? mtrx1 mtrx2)
  (equal? (map length mtrx1) (map length mtrx2)))
```

Notice that in your solution you're comparing the total length of each list (the number of rows in the matrix), but ignoring the length of each sublist (the number of columns for each row in the matrix). In my soultion, first we calculate the length of each sublist and after that we check if all the lengths are equal. For example, take this input:

```
(define mtrx1 '((1 2 3 4) (4 5 6 6) (6 7 8 9)))
(define mtrx2 '((5 4) (3 2) (7 1)))
(same-size-matrix? mtrx1 mtrx2)
```

First the `same-size-matrix?` evaluates this expression, which finds the length of each sublist in `mtrx1`. It's necessary to check all the lengths, not just the first one, in case we're dealing with a jagged array:

```
(map length mtrx1)
; evaluates to '(4 4 4)
```

And then we have this expression, which performs the same operation for `mtrx2`:

```
(map length mtrx2)
; evaluates to '(2 2 2)
```

Finally, we compare the two lists of lengths (in fact: the number of columns per row), returning the expected result:

```
(equal? '(4 4 4) '(2 2 2))
> #f
```

Notice that the last comparison will also detect if the lists are of different size, in case the matrices have a different number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

is it scheme?

```
(define m1 `((1 2 3 4) (4 5 6 6 ) (6 7 8 9)))                                                                                                
(define m2 `((5 4) (3 2) (7 1)))                                                                                                            

(define (same-size-matrix? m1 m2) (equal? (map length m1) (map length m2)))                                                                  


(same-size-matrix? m1 m2) ; => #f
(same-size-matrix? m1 m1) ; => #t
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple definition of `same-size?`.

```
#lang racket

; A MATRIX is a list of ROWs.
; A ROW is a list of numbers.
; In a matrix all rows are of the same length.

(define (row-size list-of-rows)
  (length list-of-rows))

(define (column-size matrix)
  (define first-row (first matrix))
  (length first-row))

(define (same-size? matrix1 matrix2)
  (and (= (row-size matrix1) (row-size matrix2))
       (= (column-size matrix1) (column-size matrix2))))
```

As a bonus here is a predicate that test whether an object
is a matrix or not. Compare it to the data definitions.

```
(define (row? object)
  (and (list? object)
       (andmap number? object)))

(define (matrix? object)
  (and (list? object)
       (andmap row? object)
       (apply = (map row-size object))))
```

Comment: You're assuming that all rows in the matrix have the same length, that might not always be the case - for instance, when implementing a jagged array.

Comment: @Oscar Yes. That's why I added matrix?. Now it is more clear to see how the checks for same size and checks for "matrixness" differ.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify if you want to check 1) the exact shape of the matrix or 2) the overall 'flattened' length.

what should be the result for `(same-size-matrix? '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)) '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))`?

```
1) => #f
2) => #t
```

Óscar López's answer is for 1.

If your requirement is 2, based on Óscar's answer:

```
(define (same-size-matrix? mtrx1 mtrx2)
  (equal? (apply + (map length mtrx1)) (apply + (map length mtrx2))))
```